# Coding maze in OpenGL

Tags: java, algorithm, opengl

**GOAL**

My task for the school project is to make maze in OpenGL. Currently I am thinking about the algorithm of creating the maze and I would like to ask you if that is a good way or I should implement it differently. Here is what I thought, i would do:

**ALGORITHM**

My thoughts was, that I would create a block class which would have `isPresent` bool property. Then I would create another class which would represent the map. This class would have a two-dimensional array, lets say 100x100. On every shelf of the array where I would like to have a wall I would set the `isPresent` value to 1.

Then I would render the wall using for loop. I would go through the array and where the `isPresent` value is 1 I would render GL_QUAD.

**QUESTION**

This was just my idea, however I am a beginner, so please could you tell me if it is usable or not? Or how would you rather proceed?

Comment: I don't even think you really need classes to represent your maze. just the bool[100][100] should be enough. 1's for walls, 0's for paths.

Comment: That makes sense, and otherwise, does the algorithm make sense with your suggestion?

Comment: Yep. `for(I = 0-99){for(j = 0-99){if(maze[i][j]){render()}}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion should work and can even be improved by using only booleans as mentioned in comments.

However doing so you will be very limited because closed 1x1 maze now actually takes 3x3 grid (all are walls but the middle one). It is doable but it will make your algorithms to design the pathways way harder and you basically have no chance of controlling the wall thickness (in your case it is always as thick as the empty space).

To have a bit of an improvement you could have a class that represent an empty segment with up to 4 walls having 4 booleans `leftClosed`, `rightClosed`, `topClosed`, `bottomClosed`. Naturally you could do `float[width][height][4]`. This produces a bit of a data overhead but it makes it very easy to design and extract your walls.

The basic drawing would than be to draw a rectangle for each wall in each segment. Since some are duplicated you can draw for instance only all top and all left walls. The exception then being that the bottom most row and the right most column need to draw bottom and right walls as well. (The reason being that `segment[x][y].right` is the same wall as `segment[x+1][y].left` so it is best to draw just one of them).

A more advanced procedure is generating "paths". You basically start at any position and just keep appending vertex data. As pseudo code something in the terms like:

```
while(currentSegment != initialSegment && currentHeading != initialHeading)
    if currentSegment.blocked(currentHeading) {
        currentHeading = currentHeading.turnClockwise()
    } else {
        currentSegment = currentSegment.stepToward(currentHeading)
    }
    vertexData.appendToClockwiseHeading(currentHeading, currentSegment)
}
```

So basically you start anywhere and you are done when you come back to where you started. You do need a heading as in going upwards, right... and `blocked` method just does like `case upwards: return topClosed`. Turning clockwise is just changing rotation like from `upwards` you go to `right` and step forward is pretty straight forward again. The vertex data can obviously be generated from segment and heading; `upwards` in clockwise would mean you are drawing the left wall.